# Cakephp editing BelongsTo associated field

Tags: cakephp

I'm having problem in editing associated (BelongsTo) field...

```
Class ModelA extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array ('ModelB');

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public function getModelA($id){
        $modelA = $this->find('all', array('contain' => array('ModelB'),'conditions' => array('ModelA.id' => $id)));
        if(count($modelA)>0){
            $modelA = $modelA[0];
        }
        return $modelA;
    }
}

class ModelAsController extends AppController {
    public function edit($id = null) {
        $modelA = $this->ModelA->getModelA($id);
        $this->set('modelA', $modelA);
    }
}
```

Data in the $modelA is in the format:

```
array(
    'ModelA' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'ModelB' => array(
        ...
    )
)
```

So far, everything is fine...

But, I'm stuck with the edit.ctp. I need input for editing of the field1 from the ModelB, but I'm getting empty input box. Line of the code goes like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('ModelB.field1');
```

When I try to debug:

```
Debugger::log($modelA['ModelB']['field1']);
```

then I have correct value.

What would be the way to have input box filled with field1 of the ModelB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a `FormHelper` to pickup the model data you have to set

`$this->request->data = $modelA;`

in the Controller, otherwise the helper has no idea where you've hidden the  data :)

(tip: usually you can debug the helper code in such cases)

Comment: You're right. I've found the same. $this->data = $modelA; is fine too.